# my domain name opens 1and1 defaultsite

Tags: prestashop

My domain is in godaddy and web hosting is in 1and1 webserver. I have used prestashop and installed prestashop in webserver in subfolder called prestashop. When i installed prestashop to my site i used mydomain/prestashop/install and completed the installation processes. Now, when i try to open my website www.mydomain.com is opens www.mydomain.com/defaultsite. but if i type www.mydomain.com/prestashop/index.php my website home page opens. I want my site open when i just type www.mydomain.com. Can anyone please help me. My DNS server propagation is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have uploaded the Prestashop folder in your root folder. The documentation given below has some language error. It should be `upload data of PrestaShop folder at the root folder`

From the installation documentation for [Prestashop 1.6](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Installing+PrestaShop) and [Prestashop 1.7](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Installing+PrestaShop)

> **Your needs:**
>
> If you want your shop to be the main website for your domain name (i.e., http://www.example.com), upload PrestaShop at the root folder of the upload space (which may depend on the host).
>
> If you want your shop to be in a sub-folder of your domain name (http://www.example.com/shop), you must first create a folder through FileZilla (right-click and choose "Create directory"), then upload PrestaShop in that folder.
>
> If you want your shop to be in a sub-domain of your domain name (http://shop.example.com), you must first create a sub-domain. This depends on your host: you might be able to do it simply by adding a new folder with your FTP client, or you might have to create the sub-domain through your host's administration panel. Read your host's support documentation first. Once created, browse to the sub-domain's folder, and upload PrestaShop there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Before you send me a message, I transferred all my file to root and it's working what I want.